# 98 Honda Accord 2.3L

Tags: honda, accord, fan, cooling

I have a 98 Honda Accord. I replace the radiator and cooling fan, now they come on as soon the ignition is turned on and 30 seconds later the heat gauge goes to high.I am wondering if I have a grounding problem.

Comment: check the coolant temp sensor. sounds like it may eitber be unplugged or not working

Comment: Also, the heat up is probably due to an air pocket inside the cooling system on the engine side. You may try parking the car on an incline with the front pointing uphill, then see if you can add more coolant.

Comment: Did you burp the cooling system when you refilled it? There should be a bleed valve on the 4 cylinder Accords, and if not properly bled you could see the temp sensor giving wild readings because of trapped air as Paulster2 described. Does the temp gauge do anything funny with the engine off (key on run?).

Comment: @Paulster2 : Please post your comment as an answer. Based on the description of the problem it is a highly plausible reason

Comment: @Paulster2   yeah, what Zaid said   :)

Answer (score 4):

The heat up is probably due to an air pocket inside the cooling system on the engine side. You may try parking the car on an incline with the front pointing uphill, then see if you can add more coolant. You can also see if there is a coolant bleed valve as @Lathejockey81 suggests.

Comment: You can put the front wheels on top of the curb/sidewalk and give it at least 15 minutes to purge. Sometimes it takes a bit of time for the bubbles to find a way out.